# Setting min and max value based on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had this 2 radio button and number input. What I want to achieve if radio `percentage` is checked amount value cannot be more than 100. And by default radio button will checked on `percentage`. Now assuming I checked on `amount` and enter a value more than 100, then I checked back on `percentage`, seem the amount value doesn't change to max value. And also if I checked on percentage I still can enter amount more than 100?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vzL2sx1j/)

```js
$("#perc").prop('checked', true);
$("#amount").attr({ "max" : 100, "min" : 0 });


$('input:radio[name="discountType"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'perc') {
       // alert('yo');
      $("#amount").attr({
        "max" : 100,        
        "min" : 0          
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" id="perc" name="discountType" value="perc" />Percentage</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label><input type="radio" id="amt" name="discountType" value="amt" />Amount</label>

<br><br>

<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" style="width:150px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
$("#perc").prop('checked', true);
$("#amount").attr({"max": 100, "min": 0 });

$("#perc").click(() => {
  if ($("#amount").val() > 100) $("#amount").val(100);
  $("#amount").attr({"max": 100, "min": 0 });
});

$("#amt").click(() => {
  $("#amount").removeAttr("max");
  $("#amount").removeAttr("min");
});


$("#amount").change(() => {
    if ($("#perc").prop('checked')) {
    if ($("#amount").val() > 100) $("#amount").val(100);
  }
});
```

It maintain a value less than or equal 100 whenever the percentage button is checked. You may also want to enforce the same rule for negative numbers, you probably know how to do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve ?

```js
$("#perc").prop('checked', true);
$("#amount").attr({ "max" : 100, "min" : 0 });

$('#perc').click(function() {
   $("#amount").attr({
     "max" : 100,        
     "min" : 0          
   });
   
   updateInput();
});

$('#amt').click(function() {
   $("#amount").attr({
     "max" : 9999999,        
     "min" : 0          
   });
   
   updateInput();
});

$('input[type="number"]').on('input change keyup paste', function () {
  updateInput();
});

function updateInput() {
  var input = $('#amount')[0];
  if (input.min) input.value = Math.max(parseInt(input.min), parseInt(input.value) || 0);
  if (input.max) input.value = Math.min(parseInt(input.max), parseInt(input.value) || 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="radio" id="perc" name="discountType" value="perc" />Percentage</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label><input type="radio" id="amt" name="discountType" value="amt" />Amount</label>

<br><br>

<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" style="width:150px;">
```

Comment: Also add change trigger (for input) to #perc and #amt so that input value is updated as you change selection